# Trying to delete elements from an array

Tags: ruby

Ok, I know Ruby is rich in all kinds of methods that allows deletion from an array, such as shift, pop, delete, drop, etc.

But if you are trying to rewrite methods without using those methods, then how does one figure out how to drop elements from an array?

If there is an array, say `a = [10, 2, 7, 5]` and you want to remove 2 elements from it, `a[0]` and `a[1]`, like [drop method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-drop), how is that accomplished?

Advice?

**EDIT**

Sorry, should have made this clearer - I'm trying to do this *without* any methods from either Array or Enumerable library.

**EDIT TWO**

Wow, so much commentary! =) Again, I apologize. I keep forgetting to mention that the only method I'm allowing myself to use is size. But aside from that, this whole exercise that I've embarked on (read, crazy mad hatter scheme) has actually been pretty educational for me personally. It's forcing me to to actually understand what's happening behind the methods in a good way.

I'm sorry that I don't know how to clarify this question any further besides what I've stated here.

I realize that while this question may be not the best use of time productivity-wise as Ruby does have awesome methods, I am asking for a reason and that is, this is for my own enlightenment in which I need help figuring out pieces, etc.

If there is something else I can shed further light on, please do ask. Otherwise, thank you to all the people who have responded! Really, thank you.

Comment: We really need a "WTF for?!" close reason.

Comment: You need to provide more information. For instance, if you don't want to use Array or Enumerable methods, then you should provide that actual input or your use case.

Comment: You can't change an array (or any properly encapsulated object) without using its methods.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
class Array
  def my_drop_method(i)
    self[i..self.size]
  end
end
```

Now using this method:

```
a = [10, 2, 7, 5]
a.my_drop_method(2)
=> [7, 5]
```

`self` is the current object in `context`.

here within `my_drop_method` instance method self is equal to [10, 2, 7, 5], i.e. `a`.

try this out:

**This is the new answer as per your updated question:**

```
  a = [10, 2, 7, 5]
  => [10, 2, 7, 5]
  n = 2 // number of elements to remove
  => 2
  r = Regexp.new('\d+,' * n)
  => /\d+,\d+,/
  a.to_s.gsub(/\[|\]|\s/,'').match(r).post_match.split(',')
  => ["7", "5"]
```

Comment: wow, that's awesome. I do like this, even though I'm not used to thinking in self. Thank you! If you know of any other ways of doing this, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: The OP says *no* methods from `Array` or `Enumerable`, so [Array#[\]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) is forbidden! You can use only a pocket knife and a box of matches.

Comment: @user27307254534534534543 check the updated answer as per your question.

Comment: [Array#to_s](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Array.html#method-i-to_s) is a no-no and 7 != "7".

Comment: @CarySwoveland `to_s` is a basic method of any class i.e. all ruby classes has this method. and yes i understand 7 != "7".

Comment: @CarySwoveland, awesome joke! =) Yeah, good reminder that I need to be more careful with my wording.

Comment: @SachinSingh, wow! Another way to do it via regular expression! Still learning regular expression, so this is awesome! Thank yoU!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [delete_at](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Array.html#method-i-delete_at) method, which

> Deletes the element at the specified index, returning that element, or
>   nil if the index is out of range.

Comment: yeah, no, I meant without any methods from either Array or Enumerable library. Sorry, I should have made that distinction clearer. Mea culpa.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean how Ruby itself accomplishes it? Click the "click to toggle source" button that shows up when you hover over the function description in the page you linked. Do you mean how you'd accomplish without `drop`, `shift` or `delete`? Use `slice!`. Or do you mean even without that? Loop over elements and move them over one by one, but that's hardly speedy.

**EDIT**: "without any methods from either Array or Enumerable library": you can't do it without any methods from `Array` because any interaction with an `Array` will go through a method in `Array`. This code will do it (or something very close to it) without any `Array` methods other than `[]`, `[]=` and `size` (and `new`, for `diy_drop`):

```
class Array
  def diy_drop!(x)
    new_size = size - x
    size.times do |i|
      self[i] = i < new_size ? self[i + x] : nil
    end
    self
  end

  def diy_drop(x)
    result = []
    (size - x).times do |i|
      result[i] = self[i + x]
    end
    result
  end
end
```

For `diy_drop!`, this is the closest you can get; the array will be left with some dangly `nil`s because there is no way to resize an `Array` other than by one of the very methods you are looking to implement. It is not an issue with `diy_drop`, since it creates a new array.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a.diy_drop(2)
# => [3, 4, 5]
a
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a.diy_drop!(2)
# => [3, 4, 5, nil, nil]
a
# => [3, 4, 5, nil, nil]
```

You can also "cheat" and use the `[]` and `[]=` methods with a range parameter:

```
class Array
  def diy_cheat_drop!(x)
    self[0..size] = diy_cheat_drop(x)
  end

  def diy_cheat_drop(x)
    self[x..size]
  end
end
```

(I say "cheat" because using those is pretty much equivalent to using the various delete/slice functions.)

Comment: yep, I know it's not speedy. That's not the point. The point of me driving myself crazy doing all this is to think how to do it without relying on those methods. Ruby is truly awesome in having so many methods that make your life so so so much easier. I knew Ruby was awesome, but I had no idea how awesome until I embarked on this scheme to learn more about Enumerable library.

Comment: also, if you know how to loop over the elements, and move them, etc, could you show how, please?

Comment: agh, so sorry! I completely forgot that size is allowed. The only function actually. My brain is completely woozy from thinking in ways that I'm not used to. Or overthinking. Although at this point, it's more like going in loops, and not being able to see the forest because. Thank you for writing this out! More for me to learn!

Comment: Be aware that `[]` and `[]=` are also methods, albeit with unusual names and syntactic sugar that allows them to be written in a way that most of us are used to: `x = foo[2]` is equivalent to `x = foo.[](2)`, and `foo[2] = x` is equivalent to `foo.[]=(2, x)`.

Comment: ah, thanks for the reminder. I completely forgot that.

Answer (score 0):

I know exactly what you mean: the use of `Array` and `Enumerable` methods can become so terribly tiresome.  Unfortunately, for arrays generally, I don't think you can do what you want to do without using at least one method from that class or that module.

If, however, all the elements of the array are strings, there are ways.  If it's one of  those days when I'm just fed up with `Array` and `Enumerable` methods, I would use [Object#to_enum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-to_enum), [Enumerator#next](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-next), [Kernel#loop](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) and three `String` methods:

```
a = ["a","b","c","d","e"]

enum = a.to_enum
enum.next
enum.next
str = ''
loop do 
  s = enum.next
  str << "#{s} "
end
str.split
  #=> ["c", "d", "e"]
```

Of course, `Array` includes `Object` methods, but that doesn't count.

Comment: Not sure if this qualifies. The enumerator calls `a.each` to enumerate the array :-)

Comment: What's _time_ there ? :D

Comment: @Arup, late. Too late. O&O.

Comment: @CarySwoveland .. Why so _late_ ? O^O

Comment: @Stefan, and `split` needs to create an array and then populate it.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, I'm so glad you get what I mean about `Array` and `Enumerable` methods being so terribly tiresome! =P (oy vey, edited this to add that this is a joke. In case anyone reads this literally. Judging from Cary's humor, I'm guessing he'll get it. Not sure about others. =) )